# curl with post method

Tags: php, xml, curl

salam

i want to get some xml responses from a server

but this server accept only xml request

i have this example of code

```
  <?php

$url = "http://www.pj.ma/phonexmlfeeds";

$post_string = '<?xml version="1.0 encoding="UTF-8" ?><search_requests> <search_request id="req1"><content>statut=1 AND linguistic_expansion2(lingex_qui_quoi,1,0,"qui_quoi","Restaurant",LIN_EXACT|LIN_LEM0|LIN_LEM1|LIN_LEM2|LIN_SYN1|LIN_SYN2|LIN_PHO1|LIN_ORT)</content><code>sortBy(casanet_perfect(lingex_qui_quoi));filterBy(casanet_perfect_filter(lingex_qui_quoi));setSortAttribute(indice,sortDirection,sortDirectionDesc);sortBy(indice,score2(lingex_qui_quoi,lingex_ou,matrice), ordered(lingex_qui_quoi),ordered(lingex_ou),rs);catalogBy(libniv3);sendxref(rs);sendxref(crs);sendxref(nomcomm);sendxref(activite);sendxref(libniv3);sendxref(villep);sendxref(adrp);sendxref(nomvoie);sendxref(numtel_typetel);sendxref(internet);sendxref(pub);sendxref(marque);sendXrefHighlights();</code><options><option name="maxFiles">10</option><option name="startFiles">11</option><option name="highlight_zone_start">{match}</option><option name="highlight_zone_end">{/match}</option></options><metadata><meta name="base">Pages Jaunes</meta></metadata></search_request></search_requests>';


$header  = "POST /phonexmlfeeds HTTP/1.1";
$header  = "Connection: close";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/xml";
$header .= "User-Agent: Dalvik/1.4.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; GT-S5830 Build/GINGERBREAD)";
$header .= "Host: www.pj.ma"; 
$header .= "Content-Length: 1053";
$header .= "Accept-Encoding: gzip";
$header .= $post_string;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);

$data = curl_exec($ch); 

if(curl_errno($ch))
    print curl_error($ch);
else
    curl_close($ch);

echo $data;

?>
```

but it give this response

> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

here i post a example of request captured by wifisnifer

> POST /phonexmlfeeds HTTP/1.1 Connection: close Content-Type: text/xml
>   User-Agent: Dalvik/1.4.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; GT-S5830
>   Build/GINGERBREAD) Host: www.pj.ma Content-Length: 1052
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip

```
<?xml version="1.0 encoding="UTF-8" ?><search_requests> <search_request id="req1"><content>statut=1 AND linguistic_expansion2(lingex_qui_quoi,1,0,"qui_quoi","Restaurant",LIN_EXACT|LIN_LEM0|LIN_LEM1|LIN_LEM2|LIN_SYN1|LIN_SYN2|LIN_PHO1|LIN_ORT)</content><code>sortBy(casanet_perfect(lingex_qui_quoi));filterBy(casanet_perfect_filter(lingex_qui_quoi));setSortAttribute(indice,sortDirection,sortDirectionDesc);sortBy(indice,score2(lingex_qui_quoi,lingex_ou,matrice), ordered(lingex_qui_quoi),ordered(lingex_ou),rs);catalogBy(libniv3);sendxref(rs);sendxref(crs);sendxref(nomcomm);sendxref(activite);sendxref(libniv3);sendxref(villep);sendxref(adrp);sendxref(nomvoie);sendxref(numtel_typetel);sendxref(internet);sendxref(pub);sendxref(marque);sendXrefHighlights();</code><options><option name="maxFiles">10</option><option name="startFiles">1</option><option name="highlight_zone_start">{match}</option><option name="highlight_zone_end">{/match}</option></options><metadata><meta name="base">Pages Jaunes</meta></metadata></search_request></search_requests>
```

Comment: Why do you use custom headers instead of using `curl_setopt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit this line --

```
$header  .= "Connection: close";
```

as you have--

```
$header  = "Connection: close";
```

Comment: i correct the post_string missing " in first line and also the . in de $header  = "Connection: close"; i got this error Request header field is missing ':' separator.

Answer (score 2):

For custom headers add line breaks (\r\n).

Or consider using https://www.php.net/curl_setopt for headers, eg:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS, array(
    'POST /phonexmlfeeds HTTP/1.1',
    'Connection: close',
    'Content-Type: text/xml',
    etc...
    ));
```