# How to Execute the following curl code?

Tags: php, curl

I need a little assistance. I am new to curl and dont know how to execute.

Here is the code that i want to execute

```
curl -X POST 
-H "Authorization: Basic Base64EncodedApiKeyAndPassword" 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-d '{"Customer": { "TokenCustomerID": "1234567890123" }, "Payment": { "TotalAmount": 100,      "InvoiceNumber": "ABC1234", "InvoiceDescription": "MagazineSubscription" }, "TransactionType": "Recurring", "Method": "TokenPayment" }' 
https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/Transaction
```

I am working in Codeigniter. So can anyone tell how to execute this in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following codes:

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/Transaction');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: BasicBase64EncodedApiKeyAndPassword','Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"Customer": { "TokenCustomerID": "1234567890123" }, "Payment": { "TotalAmount": 100,      "InvoiceNumber": "ABC1234", "InvoiceDescription": "MagazineSubscription" }, "TransactionType": "Recurring", "Method": "TokenPayment" }');
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if($result === false){
echo curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP can use curl library and using the curl methods you can set header and data.

check [here](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post)

OR

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387749/curl-with-post-method)